# What is the place where Christopher is initiated?

Tags: the-sopranos

In *The Sopranos* episode S03E03, "Fortunate Son" there is a [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xV7cZTAt28) where Christopher Moltisanti is initiated into the family. What is that place? As far as I know, it's the only time along the series we see that basement.

Answer (score 6):

The best conclusion I can reach is that this is simply **the basement of some unknown mafia member**.

The episode doesn't specify what this place is, I can't locate a script and (having watched the show multiple times) I don't recognize the place either. According to [the original Wikipedia episode recap](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fortunate_Son_(The_Sopranos)&oldid=46623216) (before it was truncated for space), this is just **"the basement of a made man"**. It was probably applying logic, since this is where the Omerta ceremony often takes place (see [this interesting article](https://mafianewsblog.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/new-rules-for-becoming-a-made-man/) about the ceremony, which was based on existing testimonies and specifies that it's *"usually done in a room or in the basement of a fellow mobster’s house"*). And it makes sense to do it somewhere less prominent and more clandestine.

But besides replicating the real life ceremony, I believe this particular unknown location was also chosen by the show to convey:

- Secrecy - Just like Chris, even *we* don't know where we are and feel similarly disoriented;
- Mystery - It's a dark, spooky and ominous place;
- Shabbiness - But in contrast to the gravity of the ceremony, in reality this is just some crappy basement - which fits the show's
  theme of the traditional mafia's decline in modern times.